# "me" for actions directed toward yourself

Tags: pronouns, grammaticality-in-context

Excuse me, but is it common to use "me" when the action is direct toward yourself?

- I am going to the kitchen to **make me tea**.
- I'll have to **write me a note** not to forget it later.

Comment: Better to use **myself**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeh. **myself** is better, but is **me** common enough to use it?

Comment: Colloquially, I guess so, but in the first example "make me tea" could then mean "make my tea", that is a meal. So "make me some tea".

Comment: Looking over your questions lately, it seems you're going through an old book of frequent "mistakes", of the "don't say that, say this" variety.

Comment: I started reading Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's stone. ;-)

Comment: If you are finding these quotes in *Harry Potter*, you should make that part of the question. Don't paraphrase Rowling without telling us and act like these notions are popping into your brain on their own. That's not fair to the community. Knowing where a notion comes from goes a long way toward helping answerers analyze the problem.

Comment: The quote isn't direct that's why I didn't include that. I read while I am in a tram coming home or going to work and if I come across some things that interest me in English I later ask them here.

Comment: In a number of dialects, the personal or so-called "ethical" dative seems to be used like a reflexive pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer relates to UK English: the situation in the US may be different.

In some dialects, **my** is pronounced **me**, so the first example could mean:

> I am going to the kitchen to make **my** tea.

Where tea is a light meal.

In these dialects **myself** would be pronounced **meself**, but it would never be shortened to **me**.

Note that, if the intended meaning in the first sentence were **myself** and you are talking about a drink, it would be necessary to use a determiner for example **some** or **a cup of**:

> I am going to the kitchen to make myself **some** tea.
>   I am going to the kitchen to make myself **a cup of** tea.

The second example already has a determiner.

Comment: Can't we use **myself** without a determiner: "**make myself tea**"? That wouldn't mean turning into tea or becoming tea.

Comment: @SovereignSun yes, you can, but as this answer describes, it might mean you are preparing a light meal, not a cup of tea.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst your sentence you gave isn't **grammatically** correct, it is used extremely **colloquially** (*used socially*). Being from the **UK**, there are some **localized accents** where my is pronounced as me, and a high amount of **English speakers** would understand you either way. *tl;dr*

> Depending on where you live, it can be **extremely common**. If you notice people saying it around your **area**, it's probably safe to say that it's an **acceptable** word to use as a pronoun.